# Создание двух проектов из одного в Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Обрисую ситуацию: у меня есть готовый проект в Android Studio и пришла идея сделать еще одно приложение, более дополненное, которое будет являться некой полной версией уже существующего проекта. Хотелось бы узнать, как не прибегать к созданию нового проекта и не тратить время на перенос всех данных на этот проект из существующего. Можно ли сделать копию уже имеющегося приложения и работать с этой копией как с новым приложением?

Comment: Для этого можно воспользоваться механизмом веток в Git

Comment: Не совсем понял. Не могли бы по-конкретнее

Comment: Механизм бранчей в системах контроля версий совсем не для этого. И к тому же не понятно есть ли вообще какая в проекте.

Answer (score 4):

Механизм `flavours` вам вполне подойдет. Почитайте здесь
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors

Либо можно вынести общий функционал в библиотечный модуль и на базе ее создать два модуля приложения. Один будет вызывать только библиотечные классы и иметь собственный манифест, второй будет иметь что-то дополнительно.

Оба варианта потенциально рабочие, выбор зависит от деталей реализации проекта.